# Parallel.Invoke vs await/async task performance

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing, task

Having core class with 2 methods like this:

```
public void ReadAllData(List<Entity> entities){

        //processing
        foreach(Entity e in entities){
            ReadSingleData(entities[i]);
        }   
        //processing
}



  public void ReadSingleData(Entity entity){
        //processing
        db.ReadFromDataBase();
        //processing
    }
```

I need to speed up performance of reading from database, populating collections etc..
I used first this implementation with Task Parallel library:

```
Action[] actions = new Action[entities.Count);
public void ReadAllData(List<Entity> entities){

        //processing
        for(int i = 0; i< entities.Count;i++){
            actions[i] = new Action(() => ReadSingleData(entities[i]));
        }   
        //processing
}
ParallelOptions op = new ParallelOptions();
op.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 6; //number of logical cores
Parallel.Invoke(op, actions);
```

And i used async/await methods:

```
Task<bool>[] tasks = new Task<bool>[entities.Count];
public void ReadAllData(List<Entity> entities){

        //processing
        for(int i = 0; i< entities.Count;i++){
            tasks[i] = ReadSingleData(entities[i]);
        }   
        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
        //processing
}

public async Task<bool> ReadSingleData(Entity entity){
    //processing
    await Task.Run(() =>
        db.ReadFromDataBase();
    });
    //processing
    return flag;
}
```

This above is just pseudo code. With task implementation i get around 35-40% speed up (around almost 30sec). My question is how Parallel library works internal? Does library use tasks like my second implementation? What can be wrong with first implementation?
Thanks.

Comment: You could take a look at the implementation of `Parallel.Invoke` in the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Parallel.cs,2a071ae7cdd05c58). *"If the number of actions is greater than 10, we automatically use `Parallel.For()` to handle the actions, rather than the Task-per-Action strategy"*

Comment: You may also want to look into [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library).

Comment: Perhaps consider Microsoft's Reactive Framework too. Then you can write `var query = from entity in entities.ToObservable() from flag in Observable.FromAsync(() => ReadSingleData(entity)) select flag; query.ToArray().Wait();`.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that `Parallel.Invoke` in certain cases doesn't spawn a task for every action scheduled for execution and behaves similarly to `Parallel.ForEach`. In more details, if number of tasks is bigger than your degree of parallelism which is either explicitly specified (like in your case) or defined by number of cores, `Parallel.Invoke` splits the actions to invoke in batches, in order to fit requested degree of parallelism. The actions in a single batch are executed sequentially. The `Task.Run` in contrast in vast majority of cases schedules execution in a thread pool.

In case of CPU-bounded computations the `Parallel.Invoke` logic wins as it implies efficient utilization of available resources with little contention. I/O-bounded operations change the situation as now you have lot of I/O contention which may remain uncovered in case of `Parallel.Invoke` and when I/O bandwidth cannot be completely utilized by simultaneous `Parallel.Invoke` actions which number is limited (other operations which can potentially be executed while I/O occurs simply are waiting in batches). `Task.Run` in such scenarios has an advantage because without upper limit of parallelism it can cover the remaining contention. That's why under specific circumstances it may increase the performance. There is a downside however: being not controlled the application of `Task.Run` has risk to lead to situations when thread pool is overloaded with tasks and has to spawn new threads to serve incoming tasks (when amount of scheduled I/O tasks exceeds the I/O bandwidth) which in turn may lead to the performance degradation. That's why the recommended way to deal with I/O-bounded operations is to use `async/await` because it relies on the internal mechanisms (like I/O completion ports) which ensure optimal I/O utilization.